# tips for plastic material not to look like glass vial

Tags: modeling, texturing

Here is the blend file:[image]

So I've been looking everywhere for a way to make this bottle and nozzle cap look as close to the real version as possible. I've used many different node setups I've found online to see it on my model, but I can't seem to get the same look as the real bottle. I hate to sound like I'm wanting anyone else to do the work for me, but I've never really used node for anything other than applying PBR textures. I tried changing the transmission value and adjusting the roughness, but it just seems like glass. Maybe I should remove the thickness of the bottle, so the fluid inside will look like it does in real life, but I used reference photos to make the model as accurate as possible. I just assume transparent plastic is tricky.

Real bottle
[image]

My model
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get away with a much simpler node setup. Try something like this:

[image: Bottle]

Comment: Wow! Thank you, that does look better for the nozzle. But I was meaning the bottle itself. Sorry if my question was confusing. But your nozzle nodes look better. Should I use the same nodes and just change some of it for the bottle part?

Comment: Oh. Sorry if I misunderstood, it's just that the bottle looks like pure glass in your reference image.. Byt, yeah, it should work for the whole bottle.

Comment: I think my issue for my bottle is that I gave it thickness. I did that because I plan to turn the fluid into real fluid later for an animation and the last time I tried to use fluid it leaked through my object, so I gave up.

Comment: No, you are correct. If you make a bottle with no thickness to the outer faces (just one hollow object), and attempt to use any shader that resembles glass, or has refraction (Fresnel/IOR, etc...) blender will interpret it as being solid (ie. a hollow sphere will become a solid glass ball with a glass shader). Because you want your bottle to appear as "empty" in the middle (so it can be filled with liquid), it's good you gave the bottle thickness. Maybe just a bit too thick (although more thickness is always better when containing physics sims including liquid.).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I think for the proper plastic, you play with mixes here of translucency volume scatter and glass. for glass the ior has a huge effect on the reflections (remind plastic has higher IOR usually).
But also important is to have some background for the glass to reflect something, i added one, a few more tiny tricks in it as well, adding a light with a shader to get more play in the light, its subtile

also the color of the light isnt white.
and I scaled the purple part a bit.

if you like to check here are the shaders:

if you like the screw-glass part to be more white on top, add some white object above it (make a light studio environment), so then its possible to reflect that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tried @Christopher's solutions and the shader looks good to me. I made my own approach:

[image]

- I used a Principled shader, see image
- I changed the model a bit, reduced the thickness of the bottle and scaled the fluid up
- I added transluceny and subsurface to the fluid shader.

Comment: I like how the fluid part looks better in your results. Would it be ok if I get the blend file, so I can compare it to mine and see exactly how you made your changes to learn from it.

Comment: How thick did you make the bottle